# SQL query to check if secondary database is removed from availability group

Tags: sql-server, backup, availability-groups

I have an AG with one primary replica and one secondary replica. 
I have created a script that queries transaction log backups from these database replicas and restores them to a target database.

Recently one user removed one secondary database from the AG and started using it as a standalone database as explained here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/remove-a-secondary-database-from-an-availability-group-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017. The user also started a backup chain of this database.

The script now fails to restore as the recovery fork guid has changed on the secondary database.

Is there a way to detect if a database has left the AG so that in the script while I query the backupsets, I can skip the database if it is no longer part of the AG?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `exists` with the [`sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-hadr-database-replica-states-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) DMV to see if the DB is in a AG.

> Returns a row for each database that is participating in an Always On
>   availability group for which the local instance of SQL Server is
>   hosting an availability replica. This dynamic management view exposes
>   state information on both the primary and secondary replicas. On a
>   secondary replica, this view returns a row for every secondary
>   database on the server instance. On the primary replica, this view
>   returns a row for each primary database and an additional row for the
>   corresponding secondary database

Here is the query:

```
if exists(
    select 
        DBName = db_name(s.database_id)
        ,s.is_local
        ,s.synchronization_state_desc
        ,s.synchronization_health_desc
    from sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_states s
    where db_name(s.database_id) = 'your_database'
    )
begin
--do something useful
end
else
begin
--exit, probably without error
end
```

This would need to query against the secondary if you aren't on 2014+. If you are, then you can add `s.is_primary_replica = 0` to the query. Or you can use [this method](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3206/finding-primary-replicas-for-sql-server-2012-alwayson-availability-groups-with-powershell/) or a similar approach.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following query to determine if a given database has a replica on a given server.  Replace the placeholders in the WHERE clause to specify the database and server you are checking and run it on the primary.

```
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_states rs 
  JOIN sys.dm_hadr_database_replica_cluster_states dcs ON dcs.replica_id = rs.replica_id 
  JOIN sys.dm_hadr_availability_replica_cluster_states acs ON acs.replica_id = rs.replica_id 
WHERE 
  dcs.database_name = '<databasename>' 
  AND acs.replica_server_name = '<servername>'
```